# Finding substrings in a larger string (C)

Tags: c, string

I have a program which asks the user to input a few characters. My program has a large array of letters which will be searched to see if the user's input can be found. If it's found, then the index of its value will be printed. If multiple copies of the input are found in the array, all indexes will be printed.

There's a twist where if the user enters a * character, it can be considered as any letter and will be ignored, e.g AB* could be ABA,ABB,ABC... etc.

I have my function searchArray which determines a wildcard character *.

```
char* searchArray(char *DNA, char *string) 
{
    if (!*string) 
        return NULL;
    char *p1 = (char*)DNA;
    while (*p1) 
    {
        char *p1Begin = p1, 
        *p2 = (char*)string;
        while ((*p1 && *p2 && *p1 == *p2) || *p2 == '*') 
        {
            p1++;
            p2++;
        }
        if (!*p2)
           return p1Begin;
           p1 = p1Begin + 1;
    }
return NULL;
}
```

I call this function in my main program to compare the strings and then if the strings match, I'll print the index of where it is. However I cannot seem to print more than 1 index (If there are multiple sets, it won't be printed).

```
char * result = searchArray(DNA, inputstring);
while (result != NULL) 
{
    int position = result - DNA;
    printf("Match found at element %d", position);
    result = strstr(++result, inputstring);
}
```

Comment: Your code is incredibly hard to read. You should format it better, indent it, use better names, and use {} around your blocks.

Comment: @Falmarri Is it better now?

Comment: Code does not compile.  Post true code.

Comment: `while ((*p1 && *p2 && *p1 == *p2) || *p2 == '*')` is questionable.  Maybe `while (*p1 && *p2 && (*p1 == *p2 || *p2 == '*'))`?  Not sure.

Comment: Note: consider variable names `char* searchString(const char *haystack, const char *needle)`.  I found these 2 names well understood.

Answer (score 0):

the following code

- simplifies the logic
- must have any 'wildcard' at the end of the findString
- works correctly
- makes use of the available C library functions, specifically `strstr()`
- prints the output, one entry per line

there are a few edge cases that will be a problem, however, you can handle those

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main( void )
{
    // DNA must be an array, not a pointer to an array
    char DNA[] = { "zabcdefghijklmnab defghijk ab 123 ab" };

    // findString must be an array, not a pointer to an array
    char findString[] = {"ab*"};

    // always a good idea to initialize variables on the stack
    char *wildCard = NULL;

    // Note following 'if' will not result in correct action if
    //      wildcard character not last in findString
    if( ( wildCard = strstr( findString, "*") ) )
    { // then a trailing '*', so replace with NUL byte
        *wildCard = '\0';
    }

    // get first possible pointer to where findString is in DNA string
    char * result = strstr( result, findString );

    while( result )
    { // then an instance of the findString found in DNA string
        int position = result - DNA;
        printf("Match found at element %d\n", position);
        // Note: step over first byte of instance of findString
        //       may want to change +1 to length of original findString
        result = strstr( result+1, findString );
    }
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```